# Sticky navigation hidden until scrolling down page

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm running into an issue where I have two navigation menu's on the same page. I want both to be shown separately in which one involves being a sticky navigation. I want this one hidden until I scroll down and cant see the other that appears. Is there a way we can make this work?

```
<!-- Start Sticky Navigation -->
        <nav id="mainnav">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span4">
                        <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo2.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span8">
                        <ul id="fluid-nav" class="fluid-navigation visible-desktop">
                            <li class="current"><a href="#home">Top</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#productoverview">Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#imagegallery">Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#nocomp">No Compromises</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#selectbuy"><button class="btnbuy small">Select & Buy</button></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- End Sticky Navigation -->
```

CSS

```
nav#mainnav {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: #cb0000;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Dont Actually get the full detail of what u What but this is Something i came up with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
</div>

<div id="float">
<div class="m">menu1</div>
<div class="m">menu2</div>
<div class="m">menu3</div>
<div class="m">menu4</div>
</div>
<div class="foot">
<div class="m">menu1</div>
<div class="m">menu2</div>
<div class="m">menu3</div>
<div class="m">menu4</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is the Css

```
    <style type="text/css">
#float{
    background: #09C;
    position:absolute;
    right:60px;
    top:20px;
    width:90%;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
}
.m{
    display: inline-block;
}
.float_content_head{
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
    text-align:center;
}
.float_content{
    padding-top:10px;
}
.main{

    height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.foot{
    background:#09F;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid #efefef;
    padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.43);

}
#box p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
</style>
```

And .js

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
var starting_position = $('#float').offset();

var top_padding = 20; // Distance from top while scrolling
var bottom_limit = $('.foot').offset();
var box_height = $('#float').height() + 15; // Distance from top
$(window).scroll(function(){
var top_window = $(window).scrollTop();
if (top_window > starting_position.top && top_window < bottom_limit.top - box_height){
$('#float').stop().animate({top: top_window - starting_position.top + top_padding}, 0); //0 makes it sticky 
} else if (top_window > bottom_limit.top - starting_position.top - box_height){
$('#float').stop().animate({top: bottom_limit.top - starting_position.top - box_height }, 0);
} else { $('#float').stop().animate({top: 10 }, 400);           
}
});
});
</script>
```

And fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4SVXt/903/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using `position:sticky` for your headers.

Here is my code:

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0
}


/*  This just makes your navbar look good as I didn't know what library you were using.  */

.fluid-navigation {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.fluid-navigation li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 0.3em;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

nav {
  background: #222;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
}

.contentBody {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200vh;
}

a {
  color: yellow
}

a:hover {
  color: royalblue
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <nav id="mainnav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span4">
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo2.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="span8">
            <ul id="fluid-nav" class="fluid-navigation visible-desktop">
              <li class="current"><a href="#home">Top</a></li>
              <li><a href="#productoverview">Overview</a></li>
              <li><a href="#imagegallery">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="#nocomp">No Compromises</a></li>
              <li><a href="#selectbuy"><button class="btnbuy small">Select & Buy</button></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    Scroll to the bottom
    <div class="contentBody">Content 1<br>Keep Scrolling<br>Content 1<br></div>
  </div>
  This Navbar will push the top navbar and take its place.
  <div class="content">
    <nav id="mainnav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="span4">
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo2.png" alt="LOGO2"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="span8">
            <ul id="fluid-nav" class="fluid-navigation visible-desktop">
              <li class="current"><a href="#home">Top2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#productoverview">Overview2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#imagegallery">Gallery2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#nocomp">Compromises2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#selectbuy"><button class="btnbuy small">Select & Buy</button></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    Scroll to the bottom
    <div class="contentBody">Content 2<br>Keep Scrolling<br>Peace .<br></div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Peace .